# Can't mass assign protected attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

My `features` file looks at this:

```
Given there are the following users:
    | email              | password | admin |
    | admin@ticketee.com | password | true  |
```

And my `user` model doesn't declare the admin attribute as `attr_accessible` to prevent mass assignment. Accordingly, I've made changes to the `user_steps.rb` file to tackle this.

```
Given /^there are the following users:$/ do |table|
  table.hashes.each do |attributes|
   unconfirmed = attributes.delete("unconfirmed") == "true"
   @user = User.create!(attributes)
   @user.update_attribute("admin", attributes["admin"] == "true")
   @user.confirm! unless unconfirmed
 end
end
```

Now this is supposed to work according to the book - Rails3 in action. I checked the code on their [online repo](https://github.com/rails3book/ticketee/tree/chapter_7) as well. 
Running this with cucumber gives the following error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: admin (ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
  ./features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  ./features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:2:in `each'
  ./features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:2:in `/^there are the following users:$/'
  features/creating_projects.feature:7:in `Given there are the following users:'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I really cant figure what's wrong here.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the user model add:

```
attr_accessible :admin
```

**Update:**

The `admin` attribute can be mass assigned and any hacker can set it easily by sending it with the parameters.

Comment: All this is being done to not allow `admin` attribute to be `attr_accessible` and to prevent mass assignment which is susceptible to attacks.

Comment: Correct, but this caused the error you got "Can't mass assign protected attributes", right?

Comment: True. The intent is to make a `user` object with the values of just `email` and `password` field and then manually set the `admin` value in the following line of code - `@user.update_attribute("admin", attributes["admin"] == "true")`. I'm guessing the issue is that while the `User.create!(attributes)` is called all the attributes are being passed and hence the error. Is there a way to change the behavior to passing just the first two attributes and not the `admin` attributes.

Comment: Ummm, I got it, yup, I think you have 2 solutions either to delete the admin attribute as you did for the unconfirmed attribute or pass the attribute to the create method manually: @user = User.create!(:email => attribute["email"], :password => attribute["password"]), am I right?

Comment: Thank you so very much, Mohamed. This is exactly was I wanted. I was unable to put this in ruby code, as I'm new to the language. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: people reading this answer beware. you are leaving the admin attribute open to attack.

Comment: @AdamWaite Yes, you're definitely right. I updated the answer

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work by changing the step definition:

```
   Given /^there are the following users:$/ do |table|
      table.hashes.each do |attributes|
      unconfirmed = attributes.delete("unconfirmed") == "true"
      admin = attributes.delete("admin") == "true"
      @user = User.create!(attributes)
      @user.admin = admin
      @user.confirm! unless unconfirmed
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `@user.admin = attributes["admin"] == "true"`?

You will need to get rid of the admin value from the attributes hash - so the full code would be

```
admin = attributes.delete("admin") == "true"
...
@user = User.new(attributes)
@user.admin = admin
@user.save!
```

I changed User.create! to User.new + @user.save because you are setting an attribute but not saving the model after. If @user.confirm! saves the model you won't see any errors, but it's not good practice to rely on side effects from other methods like that. Better to be explicit.

Comment: @Prakhar your attributes hash is having `admin` parameter also..check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743232/rail-atttr-accesible-not-working-as-documented/9743345) answered by @jamie itself to get rid of the error

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is based on "Rails 3 in Action", the sample code actually has the same problem. From the log:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: admin
(0.1ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'sfcarroll2@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."confirmation_token" =     'f9zDB57RDXsziBdGpmnW' LIMIT 1
```

However, in the **config/environments/development.rb** file, the **mass_assignment_sanitizer** is not set. By default a new rails 3.2 project will set this. If it is commented out, the code will execute. The default setting is:

```
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
```

The sample code then sets the attribute using a private method **set_admin**.
Is this a good coding practice? I'm not sure but it works.

It's a great book, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most easy way to do this is:

```
Given /^there are the following users:$/ do |table|
  table.hashes.each do |attributes|
    unconfirmed = attributes.delete("unconfirmed") == "true" # this will delete the attribute unconfirmed from first
    # scenario on the signing_in.feature but it's also make a variable unconfirmed true (2 in one action)

    admin = attributes.delete("admin") == "true"

    @user = User.create!(attributes)

    @user.update_attribute("admin", "true") if admin

    # with the user and password, it will create the user as admin.
    @user.confirm! unless unconfirmed  # this is work for the second scenario check rails 3 in action page 152.
  end
end
```

This way you'll delete the admin attribute from the attributes so you can create the new user; 
without the mass-assign attributes error. But for the "test" purpose we keep the admin variable to assign the user.admin attribute if the admin was true. The thing here is that you won't make the admin accessible on the User model to protect your site from a hack, but we're doing this to pass our test only. On your website you have to implement a secure way to update the user after it was created.