# Rails atttr_accesible not working as documented

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mass-assignment

In rails 3.2.1, I have a model:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible :email, :password
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :confirmed, :as => :admin
end
```

I keep getting a `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error` for the following:

```
params[:player]
#=> {:email => "some@email.com", :password => "12345", :confirmed => true)
player = Player.new(params[:player])
```

Why is this happening when all I want it to do is ignore the `:confirmed` attribute and move on with it's business. The [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#countermeasures) makes it seem like I should be able to do that, but I keep getting this exception and it's really getting to me because either I am doing it wrong or the docs are wrong.

I'd love any help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment out this line in `development.rb`:

`config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict`

The strict setting will raise an error and the default setting will just log a warning.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure what you want to happen when a mass assignment happens by setting `Player.mass_assignment_sanitizer` (or set it on `ActiveRecord::Base` for it to apply to all AR models)

You can also set it in your configuration files via `config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer`

Our of the box you can set it to either `:logger`, which just logs when these things happen or `:strict` which raises exceptions. You can also provide your own custom sanitizer.  The current application template sets it to strict, although that used not to be the case