# Can't mass-assign protected attributes error in deep resource tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, nested-attributes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't mass assign protected attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742842/cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes)

my resource tree:

```
camrade has_many resumes 
resumes has_many experiences 
experience belongs_to company
```

camrade and resumes and experiences nests each other.

I want to change all this on one page. in controller I have string:

```
  @camrade.update_attributes(params[:camrade])
```

From view after submit comes this params:

```
"camrade"=>{
    "resumes_attributes"=>{
      "0"=>{
        "title"=>"first",
        "id"=>"4"},
      "1"=>{
        "title"=>"second",
        "experiences_attributes"=>{
          "1344617107870"=>{
            "company_name"=>"Some company"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Because Experience does not have company_name, I wrote this way:

```
    class Experience < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :company
      def company_name
        company.try(:name)
      end
      def company_name=(name)
        self.company = Company.find_or_create_by_name(name) if name.present?
      end
    end
```

But still an error "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: company_name" occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `attr_accessible :company_name` to your Experience model. Your updated code should be something like:

```
class Experience < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :company_name
  belongs_to :company

  def company_name
    company.try(:name)
  end

  def company_name=(name)
    self.company = Company.find_or_create_by_name(name) if name.present?
  end
end
```

You can read more about Rails's mass-assignment protection here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment