# Can't mass assign protected attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mass-assignment

I'm creating seed data for one of my tables and whenever I run rake db:seed it gives me the error:

> Can't mass-assign protected attributes: severity

My two models look like

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :severity
  attr_accessible :description, :image, :name, :slug, :severity_id
end
```

and

```
class Severity < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :val, :severity_id
end
```

the data I'm trying to seed with is

```
statuses = Status.create(
  [
    {
      "name"=> 'Normal', 
      "slug"=> 'normal', 
      "description"=> 'The service is up or was up during this entire period', 
      "severity"=> 1,
      "image"=> 'tick-circle'
    }
  ]
)
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Related: [Can't mass assign protected attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742842/cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add :severity to the Severity model on the attr_accesible line . Rails is trying to assign an attribute by that name which I assume you have in your database.

Answer (score 2):

```
attr_accessible :severity
```

Section 6: Mass Assignment
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

Comment: Thanks very much! Great article as well. Wasn't really sure what mass-assignment was doing for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your seed says `severity`, but your accessor says `severity_id`. So which one is it?

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that before. It's always the small things. Thanks!